# Find the determinant of the AR(1) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, determinant, toeplitz-matrices

Find  the determinant of the AR(1) matrix given by:
$$R = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \rho & \cdots & \rho^{d-1}\\
\rho & 1 & \cdots & \rho^{d-2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ 
\rho^{d-1} & \rho^{d-2} & \cdots & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

This is a common question but I want a simpler method of computation that is without using results of determinants of tridiagonal matrices.
Please help!

Comment: Could you add more entries to the matrix? I'm not sure I understand the pattern

Comment: If I'm getting the construction of the matrix right, then it is a particular case of Theorem 1 in my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1383741/is-this-determinant-always-non-negative/1384516#1384516 (with all $p_i$ equal to $\rho$).

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2815525/339790

Comment: The solution of that duplicated candidate uses tridiagonal matrices, which the OP said wasn't wanted.  Voting to keep open.